# How do you properly detect the browser's support for opacity?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, transparency, opacity, filter

I've got some javascript code that applies an alpha transparency. Before it does that it attempts to detect what type of transparency the browser supports and stores that in a variable for use later. Here's what the code looks like:

```
// figure out the browser support for opacity
if (typeof br.backImg.style.opacity != 'undefined') 
    opacityType = 'opacity';
else if (typeof br.backImg.filters == 'object') 
    opacityType = 'filter';
else 
    opacityType = 'none';
```

For Firefox and Safari, the first condition is true, for IE7 the second condition is true, but for IE6 it falls to the last condition. Why would IE6 not have a filters object? Is there a better way of detecting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IE7 it is filter**s** and in IE6 it is filter.

The code below returns:

- 'opacity' if style.opacity is supported
- 'filter' for MS filter ( IE < 7 )
- 'filters' for MS filters ( IE7 )
- 'none' for everything else

.

```
var opacityType=(
  (typeof o.style.opacity !== 'undefined') ? 'opacity' :
  /*@cc_on @if (@_jscript)
    (typeof o.filters === 'object') ? 'filters' :
    (typeof o.filter === 'string') ? 'filter' :
  @end @*/
  'none'
);
```

The [@cc_on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ka90k2e(VS.85).aspx), [@if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58dz2w55(VS.85).aspx) and [@_jscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s59bkzce(VS.85).aspx) are used in a [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/121hztk3(VS.85).aspx) that only IE supports.

I have tested this on FF3, IE6, IE7, Opera9 and Chrome 1 but not on IE4,5,or 8.

According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) MS has changed the CSS from *filter* to *-ms-filter* so I don't know what result you get with IE8.

According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity) *[opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency)* has been supported since FF 0.9, Opera 9 and Safari 1.2 and *[filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(VS.85).aspx)* since IE4.

I don't like to do browser sniffing, but sometimes it is necessary and conditional comments make it so much easier to handle specific IE things.

Comment: This is years late, but @some, I think you meant to put o.style.filters and o.style.filter in your example?

Comment: @Ryley: As you say it was a long time ago, and I no longer remember the details. I do remember that I did the testing and I usually copy&paste my test code to the answer so I think I did it this time too. I no longer have IE6 installed so I can't test it. After a quick research I see that at least ´filters´ exists on the object as in my code.

Comment: @Ryley o.style.filter(s) doesn't exist but o.filter(s) does so the code as posted is correct.

Comment: @some Microsoft releases a time-limited, free VM with XP and IE6 for testing purposes. You usually have to download it once every three months.

Comment: @CJDennis Thank you very much. I heard about it about a year ago, but haven't used it. I have dropped support for MSIE6 a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

What you understand as filters is called opacity. Real filters are a proprietary IE extension which enables opacity amongst many other things for that browser.

Try [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/) for cross-browser transparency techniques.

The JS equivalents are exactly the same as described: style.opacity or style.filter. More likely problem is that your doctype is transitional and/or the item you're trying to make transparent doesn't have the magical [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)

Comment: Thanks - I understand what the filters are. What I'm trying to figure out is how to detect which kind of opacity the browser supports so I can do the right thing in javascript.